# Why does docopt fail with docopt.DocoptLanguageError: unmatched '['?

Tags: python, docopt

Why does this code fail with the following exception?

```
"""my_program - for doing awesome stuff

Usage: my_program [--foo]

Options:
    --foo - this will do foo
"""

import docopt
args = docopt.docopt(doc=__doc__)
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/post.py", line 10, in <module>
    args = docopt.docopt(doc=__doc__)
  File "/Users/rbednark/.virtualenvs/docopt-python2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docopt.py", line 560, in docopt
    pattern = parse_pattern(formal_usage(DocoptExit.usage), options)
  File "/Users/rbednark/.virtualenvs/docopt-python2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docopt.py", line 373, in parse_pattern
    result = parse_expr(tokens, options)
  File "/Users/rbednark/.virtualenvs/docopt-python2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docopt.py", line 381, in parse_expr
    seq = parse_seq(tokens, options)
  File "/Users/rbednark/.virtualenvs/docopt-python2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docopt.py", line 396, in parse_seq
    atom = parse_atom(tokens, options)
  File "/Users/rbednark/.virtualenvs/docopt-python2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docopt.py", line 413, in parse_atom
    result = pattern(*parse_expr(tokens, options))
  File "/Users/rbednark/.virtualenvs/docopt-python2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docopt.py", line 381, in parse_expr
    seq = parse_seq(tokens, options)
  File "/Users/rbednark/.virtualenvs/docopt-python2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docopt.py", line 396, in parse_seq
    atom = parse_atom(tokens, options)
  File "/Users/rbednark/.virtualenvs/docopt-python2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docopt.py", line 415, in parse_atom
    raise tokens.error("unmatched '%s'" % token)
docopt.DocoptLanguageError: unmatched '['
```

docopt version: `0.6.2`
python versions: `2.7.10`, `3.5.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It fails because of only a single space after `--foo` on this line:

```
    --foo - this will do foo
```

Fix it by adding another space after `--foo`:

```
    --foo  - this will do foo
```

Per [the documentation:](https://docopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#option-descriptions-format)

> Use two spaces to separate options with their informal description:

```
--verbose More text.   # BAD, will be treated as if verbose option had
                       # an argument "More", so use 2 spaces instead
-q        Quit.        # GOOD
-o FILE   Output file. # GOOD
--stdout  Use stdout.  # GOOD, 2 spaces
```

Additional reference: [docopt source code](https://github.com/docopt/docopt)